# How do I add behaviour to my Azure API (e.g. connect it to my back-end)?

Tags: azure, azure-api-management

I created an API in Azure portal, and it has a "product", whatever that means... Now how do I connect it to a back-end to add functionality?

I've seen many videos and tutorials (Channel 9 and others), and they all explain how to manage the API and so on.

I couldn't find any tutorial/explanation how to add actual functionality, so I suspect that I may not grasp this whole subject correctly...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You connect your own API to the Azure API in the "add API" dialog in Azure.

See http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/api-management-get-started/
=> Create an API

There is an input field "Web service URL". This is the url to your real api.

Azure API is only a wrapper which adds additional functionality to your API.

Comment: Great, thanks! but one thing though, I just don't understand, if I simply direct this Azure API service to my web-worker (or whatever) API, then what's it's purpose?

Comment: Mircrosoft says:
- Provide API documentation and an interactive console
- Throttle, rate limit and quota your APIs
- Monitor the health of your APIs and quickly identify errors 
- Bring modern formats like JSON and REST to existing APIs
- Consolidate multiple backends into a single endpoint
- Gain analytic insights on how your APIs are being used. See http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/api-management